# Bootbox not is not showing pop up modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I have downloaded bootbox.js in my project and implemented this code to show the pop up modal dialog but nothing errors or success result is printed in my console.I am getting confusing where the error is generated.

Js file

```
$('switch input[type="checkbox"]').on('change',function(){

        var checkbox=$(this);
        var checked=checkbox.prop('checked');
        var dMsg=(checked)? 'You want to activate the product':
                             'You want to deactivate the product';
        var value=checkbox.prop('value');

        bootbox.confirm({
            size: 'medium',
            title: 'Product Activation & Deactivation',
            message: dMsg,
            callback: function(confirmed){

                if(confirmed){
                    console.log(value);
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: 'medium',
                        title: 'Information',
                        message : 'you are going to perform operation on product'+ value

                    });
                }
                else{
                    checkbox.prop('checked',!checked);
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

html file

```
 <!-- toggle switch -->
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" />
            <div class="slider"></div>
        </label>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong; It must be $('.switch input[type="checkbox"]'); switch is a class

Comment: now it is showing me error like "$st is not defined"

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/85etyhfc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the wrong selector. You used tag instead of class for 'switch'.
You need to use

```
$('.switch input[type="checkbox"]')
```

instead.

Ref. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Also, make sure you have added the dependencies - jquery and bootstrap.
Working version - http://jsfiddle.net/grrakesh4769/85etyhfc/3/

Comment: my jquery version is 3.3.7 and i am not getting output in my project .. plz can u come at team viewer??

Comment: Provide the code required to reproduce it or a fiddle.

Comment: the code you are providing in js fiddle is working its fyn but adding the class point my slider changes but pop up modal doesnot appear. so if u can come at teamviewer for 5mins i will be glad to make ur answer right plz :(